Having the counter be part of the key instead of IV in CTR mode
In CTR mode, we use the same key for each block and use the IV as a counter. Are there any drawbacks to doing it the other way around? I.e. using the key as the counter and the same IV for each block.
My thoughts are that:

Using a block cipher as the PRF in CTR mode means the blocks of the key stream never repeats, which is at least a theoretical vulnerability if encrypting large amounts of data. If we instead of counting on the IV counted on the key, blocks of the key stream would be able to repeat, thus mitigating that vulnerability.

And keys can often be longer than IVs that are limited to the block size whereas 256-bit keys, for example, are often supported even by 128-bit block ciphers. This would potentially give more flexibility in how the counter is allocated.

But having multiple keys encrypting the plaintext might make it easier to brute-force. If we produce $n$ blocks of ciphertext there are $n$ keys that can decrypt one block of it, which means we effectively have a $256-log_2(n)$-bit key instead of a $256$-bit key. This could definitely be an issue for 128-bit keys but it should not be enough to make 256-bit keys vulnerable to brute-force attacks (with reasonable assumptions on message sizes), right?


But maybe there are other drawbacks to this approach that I have overlooked? Or maybe the one I did think of is more serious than I thought?

Some thoughts: Two different keys may still create the same permutation, but there is no proof. A counter on the key may be dangerous due to related keys. Use a wider block cipher. Well, you consider CTR mode, so why bother with PRP? Use PRF like xChaCha20, and no longer bother with the distinguished and random nonces.

This was mostly a fun thought that sounded interesting. Related keys is a good point, I'm not that knowledgeable about the topic and I completely forgot they even existed haha

From a pure efficiency point of view, this would require computing a new key schedule for every block. For almost all block cipher implementations the whole key schedule is calculated once-off and then stored for reuse as each block is encrypted. Whereas key schedules are typically cheaper to compute than encryptions and decryptions, they can still take a significant proportion of the processing time for small messages. Things might be even more troublesome with block ciphers such as Blowfish where the key is expanded into $S$-boxes rather than a round additive.
With regard to your third point, this approach would allow batch attacks (see section 5 of Bernstein's Understanding brute force paper).

I have never read up too closely on other cipher implementations and haven't seen these optimisations in the specs. And the brute force paper was a very interesting read! (even if a bit difficult to understand for a non-mathematical person like me)
